# How to count rows by some condition in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns:

```
type | value 
num    1
email  @
name   Oli
```

I need to count how much empty rows in one query:

```
. Count rows where not exist num
. Count rows where not esist email
. Count rows where not exist name
```

Comment: What is the output you expect based on this sample table of 3 rows?

Comment: I need to get result as:

`Empty emails: 1
Empty nums: 3
Empty name: 4` 

And write in into file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try: `select count(*) from table where type is null or type = '';`